# cfInclude without cfoutput tags

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, openbd

Ok, I have template files which I **know** will require to be between `<cfoutput>` tags, however placing a `<cfoutput>` tag around a `<cfinclude>` won't work, and anything with a `<cfmodule>` won't work as that doesn't allow me to manipulate the `variables` scope.

So, any ideas - no matter how complex - which would allow me to include such a template file and have it act as if it's between `<cfoutput>` tags?

---

Bit of context: It's for a 'framework' I am working on and requiring every template file to start and end with a `<cfoutput>` tag seems a real waste, *especially* because the less 'coldfusiony' the template files look, the better IMO.

Comment: AFAIK `<cfoutput>` has to be in the same .cfm and there's no way around it.  Unless you're doing some dynamic programming where you read your .cfm and write a new .cfm that has `<cfoutput>`

Comment: That would definitely be one option indeed, though the performance hit would be kinda bad. I considered the option in the context of an evaluate call (which is limited to expressions) and actually writing a file would be even more expensive :(

Comment: I had no idea this was the case.  That's why I consider answering questions on forums to be educational.

Comment: @DavidMulder with the proper caching it wouldn't be that bad.  I imagine it'll be sort of like a `?reinit` common to many CF frameworks.  On the flip side, is have a <cfoutput> really that bad?

Comment: Maybe I missed it somewhere, but why won't wrapping the `<cfinclude>` in `<cfoutput>` work? And I don't understand why it is better to not have ColdFusion files look 'coldfusiony'.

Comment: @ScottStroz see my blog article mate (linked to in my answer)

Comment: Wow - I never realized that. I also cannot recall the last time I used `<cfinclude>`. I still don't understand why having the `<cfoutput>` in the included file is too 'coldfusiony', though. Obviously, there is already CFML in the templates, how does adding `<cfoutput>` make it more 'coldfusiony'?

Comment: Because in good structured applications the HTML is separated as much as possible from the rest of the application. So the actual 'template' files should be as close as possible to pure HTML as possible and a pure html file should be a technically valid template file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to suggest the `render()` option, with the caveat it's a bloody awful bit of functionality in OpenBDML (or whatever they want to call their version of CFML), and I think should be avoided. I can't see how it doesn't cause the CFML to be recompiled every request, which is a helluva overhead. I think you're better off modifying the mark-up when it gets saved/read to wrap/unwrap it in `<cfoutput>` tags, that way the resultant CFML will only be recompiled when the file actually changes. Which will be really a lot less often than it's read.

Prompted by your question, I did [a bit of a write up on the CFML compile process](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/cfml-compilation-into-java-class-files.html), showing why having the `<cfoutput>` tags in a separate file doesn't work. Apologies it took so long to write & follow-up with here.

Comment: In essence I realized that this is the case as I noted in my own answer and I expressed the hope that the fact that the cfml in the pages is relatively simple will minimize the overhead, but I guess I will do some benchmarking in this area (comparing hashing+writing to disk to render() without the need to 'version' the files).

Comment: Oh yeah, I mean "as a general solution" I think render() is an awful prospect, similar to evaluate(). However as long as one bears that in mind, if it turns out it's completely adequate for your situation, then don't let dogma or pedantry prevent you from using it. I think it's a good idea to benchmark it; but equally bear in mind that it's perhaps better to take a hit on the code that *changes* the content than the code that *reads* the content. Sounds like you've got a good handle on that anyhow. I hope at least my comments were food for thought!

Answer (score 2):

What we do in wheels is just wrap the cfinclude with a cfsavecontent tag

```
<cffunction name="renderInclude">
  <cfargument name="template" value="string" required="true">
  <cfset var myOutput = "">

  <cfsavecontent variable="myOutput"><cfoutput><cfinclude template="#arguments.template#"></cfoutput></cfsavecontent>


  <cfreturn trim(myOutput)>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: That's a pretty smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found an [OpenBD](http://openbd.org/) specific way to solve this problem. Apparently I wasn't the only one who encountered this problem and OpenBD contains a useful [render()](http://openbd.org/manual/?/function/render) which takes care of evaluating cfml content. So I ended up with

```
<cfset cfml = fileRead(expandPath(...))>
...
<cfoutput>#render("<cfoutput>"&cfml&"</cfoutput>")#</cfoutput>
```

It's not a beautiful solution, as I destroy the per page compilation the engine would otherwise do, however as the cfml is relatively simple on these pages I assume this not to be too much of an issue. At least it should be less of a performance hit than actually writing the file to disk.

Comment: writing actual file to disk will compile down to a class which may work well in the long run. As long as only writing it once until modified. :)

Comment: "writing it once until modified" -> That would require me to keep track of the previous state of the file and comparing it to that state which itself could also result in a considerable overhead (especially as I have to keep track of this on the filesystem (no db access)).